# Is there a way to test if a return object JSON length exceeds max length before it throws exception in AJAX.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax.net

I am using ajax.net to return an array of records. Some request can be very large and need to be sent with several requests. Is the a way to determine if the json length of an object exceeds the max length before it throws an exception so I can divide the records into smaller returns?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to serialize the object server side before returning the request and checking the serialized string length before returning it.